# Format CD-rom on Windows 7 that Windows 95 can read

Tags: windows-7, formatting, compact-disc, udf, windows-95

I pulled out my ancient Pentium 100Mhz running Windows 95 to play a game from 1996.  This game has a critical bug in it that requires a patch.  The problem is, the computer has no way to connect to the Internet or to the LAN.  I tried burning a CD-rom on my Windows 7 PC to run on the Win95 PC, but it doesn't even recognize that there's a disc in the drive.  I did some research, and apparently Windows 95 can't read UDF format.  All the solutions recommend, of course, downloading a driver or fix or somesuch, which is my entire problem in the first place.  I tried formatting the CD-rom on my Win7 PC, but all the format choices are versions of UDF.  Is there a way to get Windows 7 to format in way that is compatible with Windows 95?

**EDIT:** I think the problem may be that I only have CD-RWs.  I think a regular CD-R might work, but I can't find any in the house.  I'll see if I can scrounge one up and try that.

Comment: I suggest you try Infra Recorder (http://sourceforge.net/projects/infrarecorder/) for burning the disc.

Comment: That doesn't to have any options to change the file format.  I burned the files to the CD using it, and it failed in the same way on my Win95 PC.

Comment: I found some options to write in ISO-9660, which my research indicates should be the most widely readable, but burning that way didn't work.  I also tried creating an .iso files, and THEN burning that image to the disc, but it also failed.

Comment: I acquired some regular CD-Rs yesterday, and will attempt to burn one this evening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I gave up on this solution, and instead created a Windows XP virtual machine.  I was able to install the game there and get the patch copied to the VM.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using Mastered format, as described here:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Burn-a-CD-or-DVD-in-Windows-Explorer

This explains the formats:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Which-CD-or-DVD-format-should-I-use

Comment: Ach, I really thought that was going to work, as I originally wasn't getting that dialog because the CD-RW already had some files on it, so I think it was writing as a USB device.  I erased everything and tried burning like a CD, but it still didn't work.  I'm afraid this is because I formatted the CD-RW in UDF format, and now it's just not going to work in Win95.  I'd vote up your answer if I could though.

Comment: Finally got enough reputation to come back and upvote this.  Cheers.